# Unable to view images while retrieving them from mysql in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I am trying to retrieve images that are stored in mysql database.I am encountering problem in it.It does not shows the image while running the code on localhost.

`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysql_select_db("mysql",$conn);
if(!$db)
{
echo mysql_error();
}

$q = "SELECT * FROM userdata";
$r = mysql_query("$q",$conn);


if($r)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
header("Content-type: text/html");
echo "</br>";
echo $row['uname'];
echo "</br>";
echo $row['udetails'];
echo "</br>";

$type = "Content-type:".$row['uphototype'];
header($type);

//<img src = "image.php?uno= <?php  echo $row['uphoto']; " /> 

echo "<img src=image.php?uno=".base64_encode($row['uphoto'])."/>";


}
}

else
{
echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

[This is the error encountered.Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWfbG.jpg)

I am unable to find the error.Please help me find it and rectify.

Comment: mysql functions are deprecated, so you have to use mysqli functions or PDO. Change to that first. @user317461

Comment: You seem a little confused about the difference between PHP's mysqli and deprecated mysql APIs

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` add this line in starting of code, then your code will work. But you have to change to mysqli/PDO

Answer (score 0):

First of all, mysql functions are deprecated. Need to change it.

Secondly, 
Change it

```
echo "<img src=image.php?uno=".base64_encode($row['uphoto'])."/>";
```

to,

```
echo "<img src=".$row['uphoto']."/>";
```